# How to correctly shutdown ubuntu in single-user mode?

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I have searched a lot,only to found that many people came across this problem.
By adding rw init=/bin/bash to the end of the vmlinuz line,I can enter the single-user mode of UBUNTU 10.04 LTS but,when I type shutdown or reboot,it just said it can't do that. Then I run "/sbin/init 0" and it said it can't connect to sock of upstart.

My guess is ,because we replace /sbin/init with /bin/bash and there is no init(nor upstart) thus shutdown can't be done.

I notice that some guy said by enter exit and I should go into next phase of  normal boot.I tried that, and the ubuntu system in my VMWare became stuck,and behave weird,at least in the sense of the CAPLOCK light which kept flashing..(CPU occupation scored too)

Any intruction is appreciated,thanks all in advance~

====UPDATED=====
I tried single instead of init=/usr/bash but it went straight into multi-user mode.

Comment: Exiting from the init process is a kernel panic, hence the flashing lights.

Answer (score 4):

When you have no *init* or other processes beside your shell, there is almost nothing to shutdown. In fact, the only important thing is the filesystem – sync it, then unmount all on-disk filesystems or remount as read-only (if they cannot be unmounted, for example, the rootfs):

```
sync
umount /home
mount -o remount,ro /
```

After this, you might as well pull the plug.

---

Another thing you could try (**but I haven't**) is to start the original *init*. Make sure no processes aside from your pid1 shell are running, then change to root directory and **exec** *init*:

```
cd /
sync
exec /sbin/init
```

`exec` replaces the current process with the one given, so started this way /sbin/init will take the special pid 1 from your shell.

However, if pid 1 ever exits, the kernel will immediately panic – so make sure you at least `sync` the filesystems before doing this.

When the kernel panics, it prints out a message, starts flashing the keyboard LEDs, and stops everything else – it stops even the loop that normally tells the CPU to remain idle; this probably is what causes the Caps Lock madness and the high CPU use by your virtual machine.

Your "some guy" was right – in *real* single-user mode, typing `exit` will *usually* switch to multi-user or at least clean-reboot. However, `init=/bin/bash` does *not* start this mode; it does not start anything at all, besides the kernel and the `bash` shell. To reach the *real single-user mode*, you would need to add `single` to the kernel command line. (Sometimes `1` or `s` works, but not all distributions use runlevels.) In Ubuntu, this used to be called "Recovery mode".

Comment: yeah!you script of exec /sbin/init did work! I run these command on a physical machine.It switched to multi-user mode as you said.But strangely, when I ran "reboot" or "halt" in the real physical machine,it did not complaint about upstart thing. The real physical machine is a ubuntu10.04LTS AMD64 box. And here I should make a correction that,the machine I mention in the question above is not UBUNTU10.04LTS is a Ubuntu11.04.